# MYSQL optimize 'IN' AND 'ORDER BY'

Tags: mysql, database

```
EXPLAIN 
    SELECT * FROM test_askcomment WHERE cid IN(1,2,3) ORDER BY dateline DESC;


id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  test_askcomment ALL PRIMARY NULL    NULL    NULL    3   Using where; Using filesort
```

Comment: Index on `dateline`? Index on `cid`?

Comment: what are you indexes? how many rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE `test_askcomment ` ADD INDEX `index1` (`cid`);

ALTER TABLE `test_askcomment ` ADD INDEX `index2` (`dateline `);
```

try to index your coloumns on which you are  using where clause or selecting the coloumns

Comment: Shouldn't this be a single index, e.g. `ALTER TABLE test_askcomment ADD INDEX index1 (cid, dateline);`? If `cid` isn't the first part of the index, then the index can't narrow the columns to display. An index solely on `dateline` would avoid a sort only on an unfiltered query. The sort is inevitable here I think (because each `cid` has ordered `dateline`s, but they won't be ordered relative to each other), so including `dateline` in the index only saves work when a single `cid` is selected, not 3 (or perhaps if the DBMS uses a hybrid sort like TimSort that takes advantage of partial ordering).